# Relational database model with relational tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

I am facing the following problem.

Imagine a relational database with two tables that are related:

**Table User**

```
  idUser | email       | otherColumns
  ------ | ----------- | ------------
       1 | a@gmail.com | ....
```

**Table Bill**

```
  idBill | value | otherColumns
  ------ | ------| ------------
       1 | 100$ | ....
```

The common relation is established with adding a foreign key to the bill table to relate each bill with one user. Despite this, it is also possible to create an intermediary table like this:

**Relational Table Bill User**

```
  id     | idUser | idBill
  ------ | ------ | ------------
  1      | 1      | 1
```

With this table, we achieve the same result but I think that with a better organization. Is any of this option better than the other ones? Or depending on the context?

Finally, what I want to know if there is any standard to create these relations.

Thanks.

Comment: Dont store currency in the value field. Make that field a numeric data type not a text data type. It will only cause you issues later when you want to do arithmetic on that column

Comment: I everytime do it based on relation. If it is 1:N I use the first option with one foreign key, if there is relation M:N I use intermediary table. I think it is unnecessary to create next table if it is relation 1:N. You have to allocate more space and the next table for someone can make difficult to read complex database design

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are standards - or rather, there are a number of books on database design that tell you the accepted wisdom. Last one I recall reading was "Database Design and Relational Theory: Normal Forms and All That Jazz" by Christopher J. Date.

The answer to your first question depends on the business domain. It often helps to summarize the system in a pseudo-language like this:

> A **user** is identified by a synthetic primary key, and has
>   attributes xyz.
>
> A **bill** is identified by a synthetic primary key, has a value, has
>   a currency, has xyz.
>
> A **bill** has *exactly one* **user**.
>
> (or)
>
> A **bill** has *one or more* **users**.
>
> (or)
>
> A **bill** has *exactly one* **user** and that relationship has
>   attributes x, y and z.

If a bill has exactly one user, you add "user" as a foreign key to the bill table. There's no additional information to capture.

If a bill can have more than one user, you create a linking/joining table, with one row for each user/bill combination.

I a bill has exactly one user, and that relationship has some other attributes - e.g. the tax status of this bill - you can use either solution. Personally, I prefer to create a joining table to show that these attributes concern the relationship between bill and user, not the bill itself. However, other people have other views.

Comment: Good answer @NevilleK I will buy this book.

Comment: @Maik It turns out that if a table is equal to a sequence of lossless joins where common columns are CKs (candidate keys) then normalization up to 5NF will never say you should unjoin that table back to them. (Because the table "satisfies" a  "join dependency" that is "implied by the CKs".) Here the Bill_User-plus-user-column table losslessly decomposes to Bill & Bill_User on a common CK so it is such a case. The answer's "depends on the business domain" is correct although its justification in terms of rules is vague. But that's why books are written.

Answer (score 1):

It is about your design. Lets say according to our design,  `one` user can have `n` bills and `one` bill must belongs to just `one` user. It means we should have `1-n` relationship. Representing this as a pyhisical tables is depends on what type of relationship you have. For `1-n` we can do it like:

**Table User**

```
idUser(PK)    |    email     |  otherColumns
------        |    ------    |  ------------
1             |  a@gmail.com |  ....
```

**Table Bill**

```
idBill(PK)    |    value     |  otherColumns  |  idUser(FK)
------        |    ------    |  ------------  |  ------
1             |     100$     |  ....          |  1
2             |      10$     |  ....          |  1
```

`TableUser.isUser` is `PK` and `Unique`. `TableBill.idUser` is not part of `PK` and `not unique`. I prefer this way to represent `1-n` because not needed one more table (one more less `join` operation in queries).

Or as you have write above, we can create relational table to link them:

**Table User**

```
idUser(PK)    |    email     |  otherColumns
------        |    ------    |  ------------
1             |  a@gmail.com |  ....
```

**Table Bill**

```
idBill(PK)    |    value     |  otherColumns 
------        |    ------    |  ------------ 
1             |     100$     |  ....          
2             |      10$     |  ....
```

**Relational Table Bill User**

```
idUser(FK)     |     idBill(FK)
------         |  ------------
1              |        1
1              |        2
```

In Relational table the `idUser` field is `not unique` cause we should allow to duplicate `userid`s `(1-n)`. idBill must be `unique` cause one bill must have just one owner. Also you can do some changes according your design requirements about is the relationship `identifying` or not.

Relationship types : [careerride](http://www.careerride.com/DB-types-of-relationships.aspx)

About design issue (ER Diagrams) : [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dbms/er_diagram_representation.htm)

ER to Tables : [tutorialcup](https://www.tutorialcup.com/dbms/er-model-into-tables.htm)

Comment: Relationships in the ER model are not represented by foreign key references between tables, but by the association of two or more key columns in a table. In the "Relational Table Bill User", the pair of columns `(idUser, idBill)` represents an ER relationship. The FK constraint from `Bill_User.idBill` to `Bill.idBill` is just an integrity constraint. Also your links refer to poor quality tutorials, I suggest readers look for results on the sites of proper educational institutions.

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion is don't creat another table say 'Relational Table Bill ' to map the bill table and customer .It is not look good to use:

Add 'iduser' column in 'Table Bill' so you can easily join billtable and customer table:

**Table Bill**

```
 idBill    |    value     |  otherColumns | iduser 
------    |    ------    |    ......      | ....
1         |     100$     |                | 1
```